# Basic authentication not working in IE or Chrome but work on Firefox

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, google-chrome, firefox

My code for authentication is like below:

```
public class BasicAuthenticationMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        private const string BasicAuthResponseHeader = "WWW-Authenticate";
        private const string BasicAuthResponseHeaderValue = "Basic";

        public IProvidePrincipal PrincipalProvider { get; set; }

        protected override System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
            HttpRequestMessage request,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            AuthenticationHeaderValue authValue = request.Headers.Authorization;
            if (authValue != null && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(authValue.Parameter))
            {
                Credentials parsedCredentials = ParseAuthorizationHeader(authValue.Parameter);
                if (parsedCredentials != null)
                {
                    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = PrincipalProvider
                        .CreatePrincipal(parsedCredentials.Username, parsedCredentials.Password);
                }
            }
            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
                .ContinueWith(task =>
                {
                    var response = task.Result;
                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized
                        && !response.Headers.Contains(BasicAuthResponseHeader))
                    {
                        response.Headers.Add(BasicAuthResponseHeader
                                             , BasicAuthResponseHeaderValue);
                    }
                    return response;
                });
        }

        private Credentials ParseAuthorizationHeader(string authHeader)
        {
            string[] credentials = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Convert
                                                                .FromBase64String(authHeader))
                .Split(
                    new[] { ':' });
            if (credentials.Length != 2 || string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentials[0])
                || string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentials[1])) return null;
            return new Credentials()
            {
                Username = credentials[0],
                Password = credentials[1],
            };
        }
}
```

I use Web API for backend and Angularjs for frontend. When I want to call one of my actions that needs to a authenticated user, in firefox I can do this but in IE and chrome I don't.
what is the reason? I think this is related to MediaTypeFormatter. Is it true?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a realm to your `WWW-Authenticate` header field (as per https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-11). Without this it seems IE refuses to remember authentications, although I can't say I've encountered the problem in Chrome.

This would result in the top of your class looking like this...

```
public class BasicAuthenticationMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private const string BasicAuthResponseHeader = "WWW-Authenticate";
    private const string BasicAuthResponseHeaderValue = "Basic realm=\"MyRealm\"";
    //...etc
}
```